# How do I skip the authorization for a specic user agent using asp.net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook, web-crawler

SO. I have an `Action` method in a controller as here below:

```
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult ToDo()
    {
      //Do some stuff
      return View();
    }
```

I would like to allow facebook crawler access the content of the razor view for `ToDo` action method. How is that possible? Your thoughts.

Comment: That sounds really stupid considering how easy it is to spoof a user agent header.

Comment: What do you propose then? @max

Answer (score 0):

create two action with same name but overload that for example

```
[Authorize]
[Route("Home/Index/{status:boolean}")]
    Public ActionResult Index(bool status)
{
}
[Route("Home/Index/{id:int}")]
Public ActionResult Index(int id)
{
}
```

and you can create customeActionInvoker